# How to hide data and display as ****

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here goes my problem This is the table

[image]

and here is the code to display the table

```
         <tbody>
          <?php for($i=0;$i<count($details);$i++):?>
            <tr>
              <td><?=$details[$i]['id'];?></td>
              <td><?=$details[$i]['officer_id'];?></td>
              <td type="password"><?=$details[$i]['password'];?> <a href="">show</a></td>
              <td><?=$details[$i]['set'];?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endfor; ?>
          </tbody>
```

where the details of officers are stored in officer I want to hide the password field by ******* just as `input type=password` how to show `******` instead of actual password in that table and there should be a link/click to show which shows the password and another click hide it the password visibility should toggle on click if I could use jquery and toggle the password visibility

Comment: `<?=$details[$i]['password'];?>` -> `<?php echo "******";?>` ?!

Comment: Well its better that you won't fetch password data and manually place values of password as `******`

Comment: Why are you displaying passwords, if you want them to be hidden? Can't you simply show *** instead of printing actual passwords?

Comment: I want to fetch password and but it should display *** on clicking show it should show the real password

Comment: Why? This a case where it can't be used?! Why shouldn't he do that? Do you know for what he will use the application? Maybe it's only local? Maybe only for a few persons?!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to show a password column but if you need to replace the password with stars this will help:

```
<td type="password"><?=str_repeat("*", strlen($details[$i]['password']));?></td>
```

Comment: Maybe he wants to show it after some action, like hovering ... there could be reasons ...

Answer (score 1):

You should simply show `***` for all entries. The length of a password is called meta data, which could help others to hack a password (think about the fact, that they know the length which is a very useful information for a brute force attack).

In code, change:

```
<td type="password"><?=$details[$i]['password'];?></td>
```

to:

```
<td>***</td>
```

The second point is: Why you save the password in plain text? You should, for security and privacy reasons, save only the hash of the password. A users password should only be known by the user itself. You and your application shouldn't need to know the plain password :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution for you.

The reason you want to mask the password is presumably so that the user doesn't see it. If that's the case, don't display the password column in the table.

If they do want to see the password or edit it, provide a link somewhere else where the can make changes but not see the existing password.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same length as the original password:

```
$PWlength = strlen($details[$i]['password']);

$newPW = '';
for ($i=0; $i<$PWlength; $i++) {
$newPW = $newPW."*";
}

echo $newPW;
```

Please see the other answers. 
-> Security

The only reason I can think of to do this is, if you want to show the password after a certain action, like hovering over the element.
This can be achieved via Javascript.

People here are always negative. But often they are right, too. So please check you security settings/methods!

Comment: It's a very tiny performance thing, but `str_repeat` is a bit faster as loop by yourself :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I just answered and didn't want to look for a certain function ;) I also tried to make it as understandable as possible! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element and then set the attribute to not display.

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");

if(condition){
       element.style.display = 'none';
    }
else{
       element.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: And everyone, who has JavaScript disabled, or can open the browser's console or can view the source code of the page, can still see and read the plain passwords of each user :)

Comment: if passwords passes through html in any way, you easily view them by going to view source, changing the type to text from password, so either way regardless its futile

Comment: if he doesn't want to hide it, it's best to just literally display "***"

Comment: I know (that's what I've answered), just saying :)

Answer (score 0):

Change.

```
<td type="password"><?=$details[$i]['password'];?></td>
```

to

```
<td><input type="password" value="<?=$details[$i]['password'];?>" readonly/></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <tbody>
      <?php for($i=0;$i<count($details);$i++):?>
        <tr>
          <td><?=$details[$i]['id'];?></td>
          <td><?=$details[$i]['officer_id'];?></td>
          <td>******<button onclick=<?php echo "alert(\"$details[$i]['password']\")"?>>Show Password</button></td>
          <td><?=$details[$i]['set'];?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: <?php echo "alert(\"$details[$i]['password']\")"?>> this statement have some error

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Comment: @ASEN can you tell me what is the error message you are getting?